# Diamondback Sorrento for first starter bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, shopping, diamondback

I'm looking to get my first bike since high school.  I'm wanting to do paved roads but mostly light trails (no jumps, rocks etc., but want it to be sturdy if I go off-road).  Since this is my first bike and I don't know how often I'll get to use it (once per week?), I'm wanting to stay in the $300/$400 range.  I understand this range gives me really basic, cookie-cutter Chinese bikes, and I'm fine with that for my first one.  The Sorrento seems to feel right sitting on it, though I haven't had a chance to ride it more than a few feet in a little circle in-store.

My questions are:

- Can you confirm that the [Diamondback Sorrento](http://www.diamondback.com/sorrento-mountain-hardtail-recreational) is a good choice for me?
- It comes from Dick's, which is, of course, not a good place to expect a bike expert.  Would purchasing it from Dick's/Amazon and then taking it to my local bike shop to do the assembly/initial setup be a good idea? or will they tell me why I shouldn't have gone to Dick's? (I just want it set up correctly and I'm no bike expert)

Thanks!

Comment: A Sorrento was the first bike I ever owned with gears when I was like 9 :) Completely useless comment, forgive me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're an exceptionally experienced programmer, you know by now that life is a series of compromises and trade offs. Yes the diamondback is a good bike for that price, but you get what you pay for. If you really want a bicycle you'll enjoy, go to a family owned local bike shop and trade a little extra money for an experienced employee to fit you to a bike that's just right for you.

Comment: While at your local shop ask about used bikes. Tell them what you"ve told us and they will point you in the right direction. If they keep pushing you to spend more than you are comfortable with try another shop. They should let you take it for a real test ride.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up heading to my local shop, and picked up a Specialized Hardrock after talking with the guys for a bit and then taking it for a test ride.  Absolutely love the thing.  Got sized for it, they adjusted it, and got a year of service as well for $400.  A little more than the Sorrento, but I think I definitely made the right choice.  Thanks for suggesting to go to the for realz shop.  I'm super happy.